# Simplify zeros in table

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

I'm making some tables of cartesian coordinates as supplementary information and I just came across some cases where some simplifications might be useful.

To generate these tables I copy the cartesian coordinates over from the output of a calculation into a table generator or into my latex document manually. The program that runs the calculations will print the coordinates to a certain precision for each coordinate. However, depending on the orientation of the system, some coordinates may be zero. For example, part of one of my tables looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}

%SI Units
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true, separate-uncertainty-units = single, retain-explicit-plus = true]{siunitx}

% Chemistry packages
\usepackage[layout=staggered-flat, arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

% Table settings
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Cartesian coordinates for geometries of the \ce{H2O} molecule optimised at various levels of theory in units of \si{\angstrom}.}
    \sisetup{table-alignment-mode = marker, round-mode = places, round-precision = 8, round-pad = false}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *3{S[table-format = 1.8]}}
        \toprule
        CCSD(T)/aug-cc-pV(T+d)Z &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{\textit{x}}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{\textit{y}}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{\textit{z}}}  \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
        \textbf{O}  &   -0.00528101525625   &   -0.00629281348635   &   0.00000000000000    \\
        \textbf{H}  &   0.95566846151475    &   -0.04134902081594   &   0.00000000000000    \\
        \textbf{H}  &   -0.20667080615875   &   0.93396881201328    &   0.00000000000000    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the document, the table rounds all the numbers down to 8 decimal places, just as I asked it to. This *also* includes the 0.00000000... entries. In these cases, I normally just replace the 0.000... entries with 0.0 (it seems silly to have so many decimal places when the value is exactly zero), which has worked well enough so far.

However, if I (or anyone else) generate tables in similar ways but with much more data, there could be 10s or 100s of entries where any number of them could be 0.000... In those cases, manually going through entries and typing in 0.0 will get very tedious and, potentially, take a very long time.

Is there some way to ask Latex to simplify all-zero entries to 0.0 (or 0, or 0.00, or whatever number people need)? I have a feeling that it might not be possible, just because I am asking for other entries to be simplified to a different number of d.p., but I'm wondering whether there's a special case for values that are *exactly* 0...

Comment: I thnk adding `drop-zero-decimal` option is what you are looking for.  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill that's *basically* what I'm looking for... ideally, it would be nice to set the number of zeros (i.e. '0.0', or '0.00', etc., as opposed to just printing '0'), but I suspect that may not be possible. Also, I thought it might make sense to leave any preamble out, just to make the example as generally applicable as possible, and to allow people to come up with solutions without worrying about removing packages, if that makes sense... You are right, though; I will edit the question to give a small preamble so the example can be run on its own.

Comment: You are asking for 8 significant digits after the decimal point. In this case, 0 and 0.00000000 mean different things.

Comment: @egreg the reason we list the coordinates in supplementary information is so they can be used by other people to verify our work, or run calculations using other methods etc. I understand the implied difference between 0.000... and 0. The fact is that the values I am referring to are exactly zero. The problem with using '0' in the table, however, is that the programs used for these calculations parse integers and decimals differently. This means using '0' as a cartesian coordinate will kill the calculation as soon as the input file is read, but '0.0' causes no issues.